# MySql PHP, bind 1 row into variable

Tags: php, mysql

Hello until now I was always using this code:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT f_name, l_name FROM users WHERE user_id=1");
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($f_name, $l_name);
```

To get the data out of the table and bind it to variables, but if I want a single result, like in the code above (WHERE user_id=1), I dont always want to use this code:

```
<?php while($query->fetch):?>something HTML where I use $f_name and $l_name<?php endwhile; ?>
```

is there a code for the bind results, where the only resould is bind to 1 variable that I can include in the code whithout the while and endwhile?

Comment: @marcio It looks like is IS using PDO.

Comment: Use [->query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) instead?

Comment: @john: mysqli supports bind_result as well.

Comment: I was wrong, pdo has no bind_result method. (not in the way it is written). So we are dealing with mysqli here.

Comment: You don't have to call `fetch()` in a while loop. If you only expect one row, just call it at top-level or in `if`.